# Formula for this 2D progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have two simultaneous progressions and I do not know how to merge them.

the top left entry $f_{1,1}$ is 1.

To move **right** across the top row : multiply by 64 and add 49

To move **down**: multiply by 4 and add 1

Resulting in something looking like this:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 113 & 7281 & \cdots\\
5 & 453 & 29125 &\\
21 & 1813 & 116501 &\\
85 & 7253 & 466005 &\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \\
\end{array} \right)$$

- What I would like is a formula for $f_{a,b}$

typing in these progressions into wolfram I am presented with:

$64n+49 \rightarrow \frac{1}{9}(4^{3a+2}-7)$

$4n+1 \rightarrow \frac{1}{3}(4^{b+1}-1)$

- How can I concatenate these formulas to get $f_{a,b}$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Caution: the operations are not commutative : if $e$ is a certain entry, is the entry which is South-East of $e$ equal to  $64(4 e+1)+49)$ or to $4(64 e +49)+1$ (which have always different values) ?

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem. How can I get around this?

I haven't had formal education in this area, so I wasn't certain that commutative was appropriate in this sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have recurrent sequence $$u_1 \quad (\mbox{given}),$$ $$u_{n+1} = a\cdot u_n + b \quad  (\mbox{where } a\ne 1),$$ then
$$
u_{n+1} = au_n+b = a^2u_{n-1}+ab+b = a^3u_{n-2}+a^2b+ab+b \\ = \ldots\\ = a^nu_1+(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\ldots+a^2+a+1)b \\ = a^nu_1 + \dfrac{a^n-1}{a-1}b.
$$

Then top row can be described by the formula

$$
f_{1,b+1} = 1\cdot64^b+\dfrac{64^b-1}{63}\cdot 49 = \dfrac{16\cdot 64^b-7}{9};$$

therefore $f_{a+1,b+1}$ can be described as

$$
f_{a+1,b+1} = \left(\dfrac{16\cdot 64^b-7}{9}\right)\cdot 4^a+\dfrac{4^a-1}{3}\cdot 1 = \dfrac{16\cdot 4^a \cdot 64^b - 4\cdot 4^a - 3}{9} \\ 
= \dfrac{ 4^{a+2} \cdot 64^b - 4^{a+1} - 3}{9} .$$

Example:
$$
f_{4,3} = \dfrac{4^5\cdot 64^2 - 4^4 - 3}{9} = 466005. 
$$

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!

Comment: I now have a 3rd sequence to add to this in a 3rd direction. Any thoughts on how I could add this in?

The sequence is $$262144n+359233$$